# Handle windows calls with in .net program?

Tags: c#

I have an application which runs on click of tray icon in windows( developed in C#). I want to minimise the application on click of escape button. how do i accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. One is to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`, and have the following `KeyDown` event handler:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Another approach is to have a button that will minimize the form in its `Click` event, and point that button out in the form's `CancelButton` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx) and return true for handling the escape. Then you can add the handler for KeyDown event and do the minimize operation.

If on the click of a particular button you want the application to minimize to tray then take a look at [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class.